# Does Eloquent handle caching of related entities?

Tags: caching, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I'm exploring Laravel's Eloquent as a drop-in replacement for my project's current, home-grown active record data layer.  Currently, I have a class `User` that supports a many-to-many relationship with another class, `Group`.  My current implementation looks something like:

```
class User {

    protected $_groups;  // An array of Group objects to which this User belongs

    public function __construct($properties = []){
        ...
    }

    public function groups() {
        if (isset($_groups))
            return $_groups;
        else
            return $_groups = fetchGroups();
    }

    private function fetchGroups() {
        // Lazily load the associated groups based on the `group_user` table
        ...
    }

    public function addGroup($group_id) {
        // Check that the group exists and that this User isn't already a member of the group.  If so, insert $group_id to $_groups.
        ...
    }

    public function removeGroup($group_id) {
        // Check that the User is already a member of the group.  If so, remove $group_id from $_groups.
        ...
    }

    public function fresh() {
        // Reload user and group membership from the database into this object.
        ...
    }

    public function store() {
        // Insert/update the user record in the `user` table, and insert/update/delete records in `group_user` based on the contents of `$_group_user`.
        ...
    }

    public function delete() {
        // If it exists, delete the user record from the `user` table, and delete all associated records in `group_user`.
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, my class:

1. Performs lazy loading of related groups, caching after the first time they're queried;
2. Maintains an internal representation of the `User`'s relationship with their `Group`s, updating in the database only when `store` is called;
3. Performs sanity checks when establishing relationships, making sure that a `Group` exists and is not already related to the `User` before creating a new association.

Which, if any of these things, will Eloquent automatically take care of for me?  Or, is my design flawed in some way that Eloquent can solve?

You can assume that I will re-implement `User` as `User extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and use Eloquent's `belongsToMany` as a replacement for my current `fetchGroups` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent caches the results of relationships internally, yes. You can see that in action in the [`Model::getRelationValue()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2646-L2667) method.

Eloquent also provides you with methods to help you [manage the many-to-many relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships). You could implement this functionality inside your existing API. However, here are some things to look out for:

1. When using `attach()`, `detach()`, etc., the queries are performed immediately. Calling the parent `User::save()` method would only save the User's details, not the many-to-many relationship information. You could work around this by storing the IDs passed to your API temporarily, and then act upon them when you call `User::store()`.
2. No sanity checks are performed when using attach/detach/etc. It would be good to apply these in your API if they're needed.
3. Adding or removing an ID to/from a many-to-many relationship will not affect the cached results of the initial relationship query. You would have to add in logic to insert or remove the related models into the collection.

   For example, let's say a `User` has two `Group`s. When I load the user, I can access those groups using `$user->groups`. I now have a Collection of Groups cached inside the User model. If I call for `$user->groups` again, it will returned this cached Collection.

   If I remove one Group using `$user->detach($groupId)`, a query will be performed to update the join table, but **the cached Collection will not change.** Same goes for adding a group.

Comment: Very interesting!  So in some ways, Eloquent does the opposite of what my model does - Eloquent acts immediately on the DB but doesn't update the state of the object until I call `fresh`, while my model acts immediately on the object but doesn't update the DB until I call `store`.

Comment: Pretty much! You can choose to work immediately on the object and update the DB upon `store()` if you wanted to, though. Just requires writing more code, rather than taking advantage of out-of-the-box functionality. Since you have an API already chosen, you can abstract away that functionality in whatever way makes sense.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll go ahead and re-implement my current design with Eloquent for now.  If later on down the road I realize that Eloquent's native approach is better, then so be it ;-)